# Google Go Templates for Web Development with two dimensional array

Tags: html, arrays, templates, go

I have a struct example with a two dimensinal array:

`type Foo struct{`
`testArray[9][9] int`
`}`

I would like to access it by a template.

For example:
`tmpl.Execute(w, foo)` //foo is a pointer to Foo struct and w is the parsed html site

How can I access the array in the template? For a one dimensional array with the old template package there is the code:

`{.repeated section testArray}`
    `<p>{@}</p>`
`{.end}`

but what is the syntax for a two dimension array? For example I must access testArray[0][0]

Answer (score 4):

I have solved your problem accidentally with the new template package. But maybe the old one works similar. Have you tried something like:

```
{.repeated section testArray}<p>{.repeated section @}{@} {.end}</p>{.end}
```

(untested)

Anyway, here is my solution with the new template package. Maybe you can use it somehow :D

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type Foo struct {
    Data [9][9]int
}

func main() {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.New("example").Parse(`
    <table>
    {{range .Data}}
    <tr>
      {{range .}}<td>{{.}}</td>{{end}}
    </tr>
    {{end}}
    `))
    foo := new(Foo)
    foo.Data[2][1] = 4
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, foo)
}
```

Comment: Note also that for web development you should use the html/template package in preference to text/html.  The API is the same but there are protections for the web.

Comment: Yes, that's right. This answer was written at a time when there was no "html/template" package available. But since it's a drop-in replacement for "text/html", changing the import path should be enough.

Comment: so the new system uses "{{range .}}" and the old system used "{{.repeated section Name}}" ?

Answer (score 2):

this little sample should help you.

```
package main

import (
        "net/http"
        "text/template"
)

type Foo struct {
        Array [9][9]int
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var foo Foo

        for i := 0; i < len(foo.Array); i++ {
                for j := 0; j < len(foo.Array); j++ {
                        foo.Array[i][j] = j
                }
        }

        tmpl := template.Must(template.New("example").Parse(`
                <html>
                <body>
                <table>
                        {{ $a := .Array }}
                        {{ range $a }}
                        <tr>
                        {{ $elem := . }}
                        {{ range $elem }}
                        {{ printf "<td>%d<td>" . }}
                        {{ end}}
                        </tr>
                        {{end}}
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>
                `))

        tmpl.Execute(w, foo)
}

func main() {
        bindAddress := "127.0.0.1:8080"

        http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
        http.ListenAndServe(bindAddress, nil)

}
```